# Maze solver issue (Getting stack overflow error)

Tags: java, stack

So we are given a maze with walls(W) open path(O) a start pt (S) and a finish pt (F).

I am trying to write an algorithm that takes the maze file and then turns it into a 2D array of points to make a grid.

Once I have the grid, I want to start on the 'S' character in the maze and try to find whether or not it is possible to traverse through the O's to get to the F. (Return a boolean true/false)

I know that this maze is solvable, so why am I getting a StackOverFlowError..?

Here is the Maze1.txt file:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOW
WWOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOW
WWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOW
WOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWW
WOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOWWWWWWWWWOWWWWW
WOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWOOOOOWW
WOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOFW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Here is my code(new attempt):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;


public class MazeExplorer {
    static Point startPoint = new Point();
    static Point finishPoint = new Point();
    final static int mazeHeight = 12;
    final static int mazeWidth = 58;
    static char[][] mazePoints = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];
    Stack<Point> pointsNotTraversed = new Stack<Point>();
    Point pt = new Point();
    static HashSet<Point> previousLocations = new HashSet<Point>();
    static Stack<Point> nextPoints = new Stack<Point>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        System.out.println("Please enter the file name of your Maze");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        File f = new File(console.nextLine());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        if(!sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a file name with the extension, that contains a maze!");
        }

        System.out.println("So, you want to know if your maze is solvable.....?");


        for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && sc.hasNext(); row++) {
            final String mazeRow = sc.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
            mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
        }

            //identify the finish point
        for(int i = 0; i < mazeHeight; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<mazeWidth; j++){
                if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'F'){
                    finishPoint = new Point(i, j);

                }

            }
        }

        // Identify the start point
       for(int i = 0; i< mazeHeight; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < mazeWidth; j++){
               if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'S'){
                 startPoint = new Point(i , j);

               }
           }
       }

       isTraversable(startPoint);

    }

        public static  boolean isTraversable(Point current){

            boolean isSolvable = false;

            do {
                mazePoints[current.x][current.y] = ' ';

                if (mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] == 'O'){ //up dir
                   nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y - 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] = ' ';  //'X' marks where you've already been


                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] == 'O'){ // below direction
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y + 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] = ' ';


                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] == 'O'){ // to the right
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x + 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] = ' ';


                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] == 'O'){ // to the left
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x - 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] = ' ';


                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x] == 'F'){
                    isSolvable = true;
                    System.out.println("MAZE IS SOLVABLE, YAHOOOOOO!!!!!!");
                }

                current = nextPoints.peek();
                nextPoints.pop();
                isTraversable(current);


            } while(!current.equals('F') && !nextPoints.isEmpty()); 


            return isSolvable;

            }

}
```

Comment: Start and finish should be on the margins, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I just went and edited my code, have a look at this new version if you want to try and help. (I originally had a lot of mistakes)

Comment: Oh and no they're aren't.(Dont ask me, its the way we were given lol)

Comment: No points are ever added to `previousLocations`, and even though you have a test at one point in the code for whether a point is in previousLocations (which it never will be), you don't do anything based on it. So you will endlessly recurse over the same points, at least until the stack is exhausted.

Comment: @DavidConrad I guess I forgot to add the point to previous locations...I'll fix that right now.  My algorithm has it so that if previousLocations DOES contain the test, then it should just skip it, that's why I left it blank.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that would make it skip it, but maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: ...oops.  I'm new to programming as a whole and thought if I left it blank, it'd move on...? How can I skip a point if previousLocations contains it?(it has already been traversed?)

Comment: @DavidConrad I edited the code to add the start location to originally be in the previousLocations

Comment: Now I get a java heap space error

Comment: You could put `continue;` in the if block, which would continue the while loop (that is, run the next iteration of the loop, without executing any more code for the current iteration).

Comment: Whoa, i've never seen continue....thanks!  Now I'm back to the stackOverflowError.....

Comment: You are modifying the same Point object in your above/below/left/right methods. You need to create a new Point object with the new coordinates. (Sorry, I have no more time now; good luck).

Comment: It seems your recursion is just called too often. Try to improve that function or maybe use another form than recursion (How about [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) or [wavefront algorithms](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150IR/labs/wavefront.html)?) edit: oh, lots of comments while I was writing mine. For the heap space error you can [assign more memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788356/could-not-allocate-enough-heap-space-to-java) to your JVM.

Comment: How could I fix it and keep recursion??

Comment: Take a look at [this nice algorithm](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/) which comes very close to your approach. The main difference is that they call it for every direction and return true if it's free, false else. To further improve it you might think about placing a flag in a second array to not search fields you already looked at.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the stack overflow error for the following reason:

```
public static  boolean isTraversable(Point current){
        boolean isSolvable = false;
        Stack<Point> dumbPoints = new Stack<>(); // visited
        dumbPoints.push(current); // pt is now visited
        previousLocations.add(startPoint); // starts with the 'S' point
        while(!dumbPoints.isEmpty()){
            Point test = dumbPoints.pop();
            if(previousLocations.contains(test)){
                continue; // This gets called, and while loop skips to next iteration
            }
          /* None of this code matters right now, it never gets looked at */

        } // End of while loop

        isTraversable(current);
        return isSolvable;
        }
```

You send `startPoint` into the `isTraversable()` method. Inside the method its referred to as `current`. You then push `current` AKA `startPoint` into the stack and then add `startPoint` to the `previousLocations` set.

The while loop runs because dumbPoints is not empty (you put `current` AKA startPoint in there).

Inside the while loop you make a new point `test` and set it equal to the top item in the stack (which is `current`, AKA `startPoint`).

You check to see `if(previousLocations.contains(test))` is true, and it is. You added `startPoint` to the previousLocations set 3 lines up. Since it does contain `startPoint` it continues on to the next iteration of the while loop.

The next time into the while loop the stack is empty because you popped out the only item that was in it (`test`). So this time the while loop does not get executed.

We then skip down to the very next line after the while loop:

```
isTraversable(current);
```

Which starts everything I just stated all over again. This runs forever until your computer runs out of memory. Hence your error.

**Suggestion**
I would suggest trying a different approach. You asked a question about this problem yesterday I believe and someone else suggested pushing all neighboring points into the stack. I think this is a good idea. Instead of pushing the current item into the stack you can push all neighboring O's into the stack and then recursively call the `isTraversable` method on those points. This would continue until a true or false is returned and you'll have your answer.

This is probably one of the cleaner approaches that you could use that isn't all that far off from the code you have already created.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the adivce on a new approach.  Please take a look at my code for your suggestion....(see edit)

Comment: it looks like you're struggling, now, with finding a link between x,y coordinates and Point objects. Perhaps it would be easier to make the 2D array an array of MazeSquare objects. Each square has a value: O, W, S or F and an X and Y value for its location in the array.

You can't change the values of the maze to X to mark visited locations. If one O can then move in all 4 directions (intersection of the maze maybe) then you'd turn it to an X and never be allowed to go back and visit the other directions.

Comment: I wrote up another version, i really don't want to have to change all of that on my structure.....how's this now?  Is there anything i can do with it? I get an array index out of bounds exception