# Fails to start tomcat in Netbeans when heap size in increased

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, heap-memory

I'm having a problem strating Tomcat 7.0.67 64-bit in Neatbeans when heap size is increased to more then 1G.

I've tried to increase heap size whith following VM options:

```
-Xmx2G
```

and

```
Xss1M -Xms512M -Xmx2G  -XX:NewSize=1G -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
```

The error that I'm getting in Tomcat log is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-flex] in context with path 
        [/DM] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception 
        is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

On the machine there is 8GB of RAM.

Everithing works fine with VM option

```
-Xmx1G
```

Any suggestion what can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are facing smells like a [tomcat contiguous memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788356/could-not-allocate-enough-heap-space-to-java) problem...

Well, you say your tomcat is 64-bit so it shouldn't be the case, BUT it is not Tomcat but your JVM witch have to be 64 bits.

So the first thing to do is to verify that you are running a 64 bit JVM. Open a console and run java -version. If the JVM is 64 bits try starting tomcat again from that console.

If it works then the JVM of your netbeans has to be 32 and hence the problem...

Comment: My pleasure. Believe me A LOT of years working with tomcat ;)